# I want check each element in the stack collection and print it in reverse. the print out should print each element as long as its in ascending order

Tags: java, data-structures, methods, stack, recursive-datastructures

The assignment is to print in reverse. each element is on size larger than the previous. so when the order is disrupted it should stop.

```
public class Program {
    private void printWordRun(ArrayList<String> words) {

        
        for(int i = words.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            String str = words.get(i);
            if(str.length() < words.size()) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }

        }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.testPrintWordRun();
}

private void testPrintWordRun() {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("I");
        words.add("am");
        words.add("cat");
        words.add("with");
        words.add("happy");
        words.add("dog");
        words.add("sitting");

        System.out.println("Testing printWordRun...");
        printWordRun(words);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the print should be :

happy
with
cat
am
I

I get :

dog
happy
with
cat
am
I

Comment: Did you mean *each element is **one** size larger than the previous*?. As I understand, you want to print if length of a string is one smaller than the next one.

Comment: My task is to implement printWordRun so that it prints whatever word run it can find starting from the beginning of the input list, words. The word run should be printed in reverse order, with each word on a separate line. PRINTOUT: 'happy', 'with', 'cat', 'am', 'i'. so as you can see each words letter count is one larger than the next. I wrote the for loop in the code. my printout when i execute the code is: 'dog', 'happy', 'with', 'cat', 'am', 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if the length of the current string is bigger than the length of the previous one, we need to get the previous string and its length:

```
if (str.length() > words.get(i-1).length())
```

When you're using:

```
if(str.length() < words.size())
```

you're actually checking if the length of the current string is bigger than the size of the `ArrayList words`.

---

Also, checking if the order is disrupted shouldn't be done in reverse. If it's in reverse the output should be:

```
sitting
dog
```

You might want to create a new list in `printWordRun` with all the elements in `words` until the order is disrupted, and then print it in reverse.

Pseudo code:

```java
// The output always contains the first word
list reverseList (words[0]);

// start from the second word
for(word in words)
    if word.size == previous_word.size - 1 -> add word to reverse

// start from the end of reverse
for(word in reverse)
    print word
```

Comment: I cant change the arraylist method thats part of the assignment. its fairly easy but not for a newbie as myself. thanks for your  input. helped me break a mental wall, but Im still struggling with getting the list order as per the assignment expectation. I changed the loop to : for(int i =0; i < words.size(); i++) and then i get an error message : indexoutofBoundsException and no printout

Comment: I meant that in the method `printWordRun` you could create a new list, and add all the strings from the `words` list to it until the order is disrupted. Then, you could print that new list from the last element :)

Comment: Also, if you change the loop to run from the start, check that you compare the current string with the next one (`i+1`) and not with the previous one.

Comment: i have to use a for loop per assignment guidelines. how can i create to variables, first one that is the first index and a second variable that is the next one to compare them one by one and print the list?

Comment: So the first variable could be the index of the current word, and the next variable will be the previous word - so you could check if the sizes don't disrupt the order. (I added pseudo code to make my idea clearer :) )

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the last before element, check if the length of the current string is one less than the next one. If yes, print it.

```
for(int i = words.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    String str = words.get(i);
    if(str.length() ==  words.get(i + 1).length() - 1) {
         System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: After running your code i get this ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7